# How to read files from local disk drives like D:// or E:// or C://

Tags: java, string, file, bufferedreader, filereader

I have the code below to find the List of files in a specified directory that have a particular word .

- **isWordPresent(word,filepath)** method will give whether the word is contained in the path defined.

The code works absolutely fine until we have some folders inside the local drives.

Eg: String directoryName="*D://FOLDER1*"

I am not able to do the same , however, with local drives. All combinations of the following gace NullPointerException at *//Code line C* (as shown in the code snippet).

```
 - String directoryName= "*D://*"  OR String Directorypath = "*D:/*"  
 - String directoryName= "*D:\\*"  OR String directoryName= "*D:\*"
```

( "D:\" would need an escape character, however, I have tried all combinations )

IMportantly, i tried **replacing the *code line A* to:**

```
  `File[] roots = File.listRoots();                            //code line A
 if(Arrays.asList(roots).toString().contains(directoryName)){ //code line B`
```

*where **String directoryName = "C:\"**  and accordingly closed brackets.*

The above changes worked until *//Code line C* where it showed NullpointerException

**Is there a way i can access the D Drive?**

> 

```
 `public void listFilesHavingTheWord(String directoryName,String word)
 throws IOException{
             File directory = new File(directoryName);
             //get all the files from a directory
             File[] fList = directory.listFiles();    //code line A
                                                      //code line B
             for (File file : fList){                 //code line C
                 if (file.isFile()){
                    String filepath=file.getAbsolutePath();
                    if(isWordPresent(word,filepath)){
                        int index=file.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
                        if (index > 0) {
                            String fileNameWithoutExt = file.getName().substring(0, index);
                            System.out.println("word \""+word+"\" present in file--> "+fileNameWithoutExt);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                    listFilesHavingTheWord(file.getAbsolutePath(),word);
                 }
             }
         }`
```

Comment: You have the escaping backwards.  It's `"D:\\"` or `"D:/"`

Comment: No, the rpoblem is not with that @JimGarrison

Comment: @shwetha: I tried your code with directoryName as "C://". It is displaying me all the files under C drive. Can you please make me understand bit more on your problem. Do you have any files under D:// drive?

Comment: @lathy, The code is does NOT display files under given Directory. This code is to display file names having a certain Word (passed as parameter)  . Also, i pass "directory path" under which the files contain . Say, i pass listFilesHavingTheWord("D://Folder1","MOBILE"), the code would display Files under "D://Folder1" that have the word "MOBILE" in the file

Comment: Basically from your question, you get NPE at line C when you pass C://. In that case why dont you do a Null check before you iterate

Comment: @lathy, the question is how i would access D: drive. The code would not give any null pointer if the Given word IS NOT FOUND. The problem is in Accessing the local disk D: or any other root drives

Comment: I try giving the directoryName as D:// and I could able to access all the files inside it

Comment: try using D:\\ for `directoryName`

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new `File` object using

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);
```

`directoryName` needs to be a valid name. If it isn't `directory.listFiles()` returns `null` and you get the NPE on line C.

In your question you said you tried `"*D://*"` and various other variants all with wildcard characters (`*`) in them. This is not a valid file/directory name.

You need to provide a valid `directoryName` (without wildcards). So using just `directoryName = "D:\\";` should work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of providing manually you can use below code for all drive

```
   File[] roots = File.listRoots();
    for(int i = 0; i < roots.length ; i++){
        System.out.println("drive: " + roots[i]);

         //call listFilesHavingTheWord method here
}
```

and call `listFilesHavingTheWord` method here and pass parameter;

in this for loop, it will ist all drive one by one

Comment: I have mentioned , File[] roots = File.listRoots(); does not work

Comment: post the output of File.listRoots(). i want to check list of drives

Comment: drive: C:\
drive: D:\
drive: Q:\

Comment: so output is C:\ , D:\ Q:\  right? not drive word after these